# Removing line numbers (not entire line) from a file in unix

Tags: bash, unix, numbers, line

How can I remove line numbers from a file if the line numbers have been added by 'nl'?

example:

file1:

```
   word1 word2
   word3
   word4
```

After command: `nl file1 > file2`
This is the exact command used.

file2:

```
1 word1 word2
2 word3
3 word4
```

Here comes the part where it revolves around.
Removing the line numbers from file2 and storing the lines in file3 (Or if possible, removing the numbers in file 2 whilst keeping the lines in file 2).

file3:

```
   word1 word2
   word3
   word4
```

Comment: Don't have access to linux now, but please have a look at `man cut`.

Comment: You have to tell how was the line number added by `nl`, `nl` has many options to add linenumber. e.g. if empty line also with line number, what is the format of a linenumber? what is the number-separator?... without those info, it's hard to give precise answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/ *[0-9]*.//' file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep. As it was answered here: 
you can use awk:

```
cat file | awk '{print $2}' > newfile
```

you can use cut:

```
cat file | cut -f2 > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

The cut utility will work.  In this case, you have only one word in the line, so you can use just `cut -f2`, but if you had more columns, `cut -f2-` will preserve all except the first.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should solve it:

```
cut -d\  -f2- < file1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove only the first word/number from each string in file2 and put the rest in file3:

```
awk '{$1 = ""; print $0;}' file2 > file3
```

file3:

```
 word1 word2
 word3
 word4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't just cp file1 file3....

```
ni file1 > file2
sed 's/[0-9]*[ ]*\(.*\)$/\1/' file1 > file3
```